# Link Linux .s file to a Windows program

Tags: assembly, g++, mingw

Is it possible to link a .s file generated by LLVM in Linux section layout with a Windows program? I need to use ISPC to generate some code, then cross compile them for Windows and Linux. I know there is a Windows ISPC port, but I want to keep the entire development environment to be pure Linux.

Attached is how I compile my program:

`ispc simple.ispc -O2 --emit-asm -o simple_ispc.s`

`g++ simple.cpp simple_ispc.s -O2 -o simple`

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ simple.cpp simple_ispc.s -o simple.exe`

`rm -f *.o *.s`

Mingw throws tons of errors when processing the .s generated by ISPC. G++ for Linux compiles the program just fine. Mingw can not recognize `.size` and `.type` directives, as well as `rodata` section.

I also tried to link .o generated by ISPC, with apparent failure consequence.

Comment: Those directives give errors because they're used differently in ELF targets (eg. Linux) than PECOFF targets (Windows). Since you're using a Windows port of GCC (MinGW-w64) under Linux, you should see the the Windows port of ISPC is available as a cross compiiler under Linux.

Comment: Well, ispc does not have a cross compiling port.

Comment: Unfortunately that means there probably isn't an easy solution to your problem. The errors you received are just the tip of the ice burg. The code that IPSC generates for Linux will follow the Linux x86_64 ABI while the code it generates for Windows will follow Microsoft's x64 calling conventions. The generated code will also use Linux APIs on Linux and Windows APIs on Windows.

Comment: Then is it possible to let ISPC to generate LLVM byte code, then I use LLVM to generate Windows object code, and finally use mingw to link everything together? I am 100% sure there are no syscalls in my code.

Comment: That would be the first step to making your own cross-compiling version of ISPC, but then you'd still have the API problem. Your code may not make API calls but the ISPC generated code does. See this article for discussion about a Windows-hosted Linux-targetting ISPC cross-compiler: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/an-embree-based-viewport-plugin-for-autodesk-maya

Comment: You can annotate the function prototypes on the C++ side with a calling convention attribute, so mingw can correctly call a sysv abi function even on windows. You should assemble as ELF, then use objcopy to turn it into a COFF object.

Comment: Can you kindly give me some more detailed instructions? I was working on creating a cross compile ISPC for the last couple hours, with no luck. I will be very happy to be able to stick with official ISPC.

Comment: I used the following command `objcopy --output-format=pe-x86-64 xx.o xx.obj`, then managed to link it successfully. However, Windows can not execute this program. I tried the ELF .o generated by ISPC and GCC, and the latter one won't even compile, ld terminated with a seg fault.